# How will a page with two Html elements that have the same ID affect Google Indexing?

Tags: css, caching, seo, indexing, web-crawler

I have the following code:

```
<div id="myContent"> 
    An image, or another div with some text... Lore ipsum ... 
</div>
<div id="myContent">
    Other divs images... and other content... 
</div>
```

I know that the id of a html element must be unique. I am aware that [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) attribute description but my client wants to keep the DIVs without changing the id to a class or without changing the second id to have a unique name.

I was wandering, is this unusual way of writing html code affecting the way Google is crawling the page? Is Google indexing this as any regular page or is skipping content or lowering the rank because of this issue?

I can't find official documentation on how Google works on this issue and I am afraid this is affecting a dozen of pages that I will then need fixing.

Comment: Has your client explained *why* s/he wishes to use invalid (and error-prone) HTML? This isn't necessarily a criticism, but there may be an underlying problem that s/he believes this will (somehow) solve. It's a rare occurrence to have a client that specifically wishes to have, or retain, *any* given HTML element, let alone an element's (otherwise meaningless) *attribute*.

Comment: I can't think of any valid reason not to just switch it to a class and keep the same style code...

Comment: Tell your client that it DOES affect Google search (even though noone but Google will ever know the algorithm), and change the ID.  You as a programmer, solution developer, what have you, have a responsibility to not deliberately write broken code and you must whip those clients into shape - they don't have a clue what they are talking about (speaking from experience).  Explain to them that this could have a negative consequence.

Comment: seo questions would probably be better asked on the webmasters site. But yes, you should tell your client that deliberately pushing out bad html is going to lower their webmaster ranks, e.g. "hey, look at this idjit with the duplicate IDs..."

Answer (score 2):

Violating the unique ID won't *necessarily* cause problems for web spiders, but it may stop your markup from validating and will also have implications for anything that relies on the "there can be only one" nature of the ID attribute, such as a CSS selector or Javascript.

Your client is misguided.  You're the expert.  Pull rank.

Comment: +1 Well said. 'Pull rank' - that's the phrase I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For some pages, Google displays anchor links in the search result, so that visitors can directly jump to a section of the page.

If the page of your client would be one of those sites where Google thinks it would be useful, this would not be possible, because you'd need different `id`s for that, obviously.

However, Google will add these links probably only for pages with some kind of ToC (like Wikipedia). So this wouldn't work for your site anyway, because you wouldn't be able to jump to both of these `div` elements.